# How to snapshot the video object and save to remote server specified by a url in actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

There is two problems:

1. How to generate the bytes from the `video` object
2. How to submit the bytes to remote server? I found these classes are missing in **AS2**:`flash.net.URLRequest`,`flash.net.URLLoader`

Are the above possible in **AS2** ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in AS2, but hardly recommendable. AS3 would be much more appropriate for the job.

Here's an old example of it being done in AS2, as you can see it executes very slow, and is cumbersome to implement, compared to AS3, I would guess:

http://www.flash-db.com/Tutorials/snapshot/index.php